# How do I use the onBeforeUnload event with Script#?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, script#

I'm using the Script# library with ASP.NET. I want to listen and respond to the `onBeforeUnload` browser event.

I am currently intercepting the event like this:

```
Window.AttachEvent( "onbeforeunload", OnNavigateAway );
...
private void OnNavigateAway()
{
    Script.Alert("You're leaving.");
}
```

But the second parameter to `Window.AttachEvent` is a `DOMEventHandler`, which has a return type of `void`. To use the `onBeforeUnload` event, I need to be able to return a string value, which the browser uses as the confirmation message.

Is there any way to do this without emitting a script literal or hand coding JavaScript? I would really prefer to stay in the compiled C# -> JavaScript as much as possible.

In case it matters, I'm using version 0.5.5 of the Script# library, which isn't the latest version, but I am restricted to this for now.

---

UPDATE: DuckMaestro answered my question perfectly, but it still didn't work for me. It is the correct answer to my question in that the compiled JavaScript is exactly what I was expecting and wanting. But it doesn't have the desired effect of causing the browser to issue a warning prompt.

I do have a work-around, though, in case someone else stumbles across this answer and wants to know how I initially hacked it into working. Instead of this:

```
public delegate string BeforeUnloadDelegate();
...
Window.AttachEvent( "onbeforeunload", (DOMEventHandler) (Object) 
    new BeforeUnloadDelegate(OnNavigateAway) );
```

I did this:

```
Script.Literal( "window.onbeforeunload = this._onNavigateAway" );
```

This is bad form for a number of reasons. This will only work on the .debug.js class that Script# generates; Script# changes the names in the release version, so the script emitted by the Script.Literal statement won't match up. Also, it negates a lot of the benefits of using Script# in the first place. (For example, using Visual Studio's refactoring tools to rename `OnNavigateAway` to something else will leave an orphaned reference in the string.) Also, the C# code declares the method as `OnNavigateAway`, whereas the `Script.Literal` has to refer to `this._onNavigateAway`.

Still, if, like me, you're on a deadline and looking for a hack, this is a place to start. If I make any more progress on a more correct version, I'll update this question with the details.

Thanks again to DuckMaestro for answering the question I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would declare a new delegate type

`public delegate string BeforeUnloadCallback();`

and then change your attachEvent code to

`Window.AttachEvent( "onbeforeunload", (DOMEventHandler)(Object) new BeforeUnloadCallback(OnNavigateAway) );`

I'm not positive that will work on 0.5.5, but it's the kind of trick I use from time to time in 0.6.x.

Comment: Wow, neat trick! That emitted exactly the Javascript I was looking to emit. The return value still isn't being interpreted by the browser, but I suspect strongly the issue is with the way AttachEvent is called by Script#. I'll keep looking for an answer. Thanks so much for your help, though -- that will come in handy down the road!